# 301 Redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

To start, I know this is liked the nth time this has been asked here, but I've looked and tried the answers to the other posts and they didn't work.

Anyway, I'm trying to redirect all out pages from the old domain to the new one with the same address (olddomain.com/this-page will go to newdomain.com/this-page). This seemed to be the best one to work:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

While that redirects olddomain.com to newdomain.com, the subdirectories, other pages, etc doesnt seem to work. When I type in the URL, I see the status change at the bottom say "Waiting for newdomain.com", but it still loads the page from olddomain.com

So I really would appreciate it if someone would tell me how to completely redirect all the pages from olddomain.com onto newdomain.com.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately that didn't work either. The status shows that it is "waiting for newdomain.com" but it still loads the page from olddomain.com for some reason.

If it helps, our Web Hosting provider is GoDaddy.

Comment: may be, your new domain is not pointed yet. Is your newdomain working properly? Kindly, upload any test file on newdomain and check. Thanks.

Comment: newdomain definitely works, as I've been working on it for the past week :)

Comment: ok...where have you placed the .htaccess file with the above mentioned code? Thanks.

Comment: I've put the code at the very bottom. Should I put it at the very top? Also, should I delete the other codes?

Comment: Is your problem solved? If not, then, kindly share your htaccess file as the position matters in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Ok...great...enjoy... :)

Comment: Note that this redirects to the homepage, unlike the OPs code which already does the correct thing and redirects `olddomain.com/this-page` to `newdomain.com/this-page`.

Comment: @w3dk yup, thanks :)

other question. how do i prevent /wp-admin/ from redirecting to newdomain.com? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin` didn't seem to work

Comment: @ZackHowler That's the sort of thing, that would prevent the following `RewriteRule` from being processed if the request _contained_ `wp-admin` anywhere in the URL. You should perhaps update your question - or ask another question. The problems you are having seem to be the result of simply placing the directives in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file. As user1544541 noted, order matters. Since you mention `wp-admin`, you presumably have a WordPress front controller (block of rewrite code) that routes all the URLs?

Comment: actually, the code DID work but it seemed that it didn't because wp-login is redirecting to the new domain lol :D

anyway, one subdirectory is also being tasked to not be redirected, so that's a new challenge for me

Comment: @w3dk: "Note that this redirects to the homepage", code updated and it'll now redirect page-wise. Thank you.

Comment: @Zack Howler: "how do i prevent /wp-admin/ from redirecting to newdomain.com? ", code updated and now /wp-admin will redirect to newdomain.com/wp-admin. Kindly, check. Thanks.